# Angular 5: issues while reloading with initial navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a weird issue when it comes to setting the base path for an Angular 5 application.

To clarify my situation: i have multiple html documents and each of it is using a different module except the index.html which is loading all modules. So in fact my app is not a SPA, but different modules which are working independently by lazy loading.

I want the base href to be always the current HTML-Document. For this purpose i set the APP_BASE_HREF token in my application to the following:

```
{
    provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
    useValue: '/' + (window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] || '')
}
```

The first visit to a page in my app is working fine and Angular is loading the correct module for search. For example:

https://localhost:4200/suche.html

After Angular is loaded it adds a trailing slash to the URL, which seems logic to me, because angular is initially navigating to the root.

The problem comes, if i open the same page with the trailing slash (for example on reload). If i do this, then for some reason the URL is still

https://localhost:4200/suche.html/

but in fact the index.html is loaded and displayed.

Can anyone help me with that issue. Maybe the problem lies in the special treatment of the modules with the lazy loading.

Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I found out now, whats going on, but i am stil not able to solve the issue. When i go to page https://localhost:4200/suche.html browser is opening the page and Angular loads as expected, doing its initial navigation to root by adding the slash.

When i now reload the page, the Browser tries to access https://localhost:4200/suche.html/, which is a non existing directory, therefore the browser falls back to index.html

I cannot wrap my mind about how to solve this issue, that i cannot reload the page with the trailing slash added by angular?

Anyone with a solution here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you wanna say that when you reload the app, the module is not loaded?

Comment: No, the modules are loaded well. It is really that index.html is shown in the browser, but the URL is https://localhost:4200/suche.html/

Comment: First I really don't understand why you include files like suche.html. You have routes and components. And with your code in useValue you set (when you refresh your localhost:4200/suche.html" your base href will be set to localhost:4200/suche.html". I would suggest you to set  <base href="/" target="_blank"> in index html and then in app.routes you define your routes/components.

Comment: Maybe i clarified the current situation not well enough. I am not using Angular 2 in a way it was really designed for. I dont have a single page application. I have different independent modules and i am using each of them independently on a different HTML page in a website. I am achiving this by using a custom bootstrap function which was proposed here: https://blog.novatec-gmbh.de/angular-2-in-a-multi-page-application/

As an example i have a module which a search functionality and thats why this module is included in a separate HTML-Page named search.html